# HTTP Port 80 cannot open in Linux

Tags: linux, http, port80

I want to use HTTP port 80 in Linux. I already allow the port in firewall by using this command:

```
sudo ufw allow 80/tcp
```

Then, I'm using this command to check the status:

```
sudo ufw status
```

It shows that the port is successfully allowed in the firewall. But I still cannot use that port which I got `service is unavailable`. I try to check the port by using `sudo nmap localhost`, but the HTTP is still closed.

Can anyone help? is that the port is already open or not?

Comment: Is there some kind of server running on that port? There must be something that responds on that port to be recognized as a open/active port by `nmap`

Comment: i want to use that port to connect between robomotion and integromat. but it shows service is unavailable. is that because the port is closed? @Mime

Comment: As i said, have you some service running that is listening for incoming connections on that specific port? `Service is unavaible` could also refer to the [`HTTP Status 503`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503), which then again means that the port is open, but that there is a problem with the application listening on that port.

Comment: yes.. robomotion is running by using that port. but the integromat cannot listen to that... @Mime

Comment: Please ensure that both applications are configured correct, as `Service is unavailable` may also refer to `robomotion` not being able to answer for some reason, and NOT that the firewall blocks port `80`

Comment: i try using postman, just to check the working port. if I'm using another port like 9090. it can listen to the robomotion. but when using port 80, it failed to listen. since integromat is a web-based webhook, I need to use HTTP port 80 to connect them, right? @Mime

Comment: No, AFAIK you can use any `TCP`-Port, you just need to change the port for `integromat`. From your last comment, it sounds like there is already a service running on port 80, which you need to stop in order to let `robomotion` use port 80.

Comment: there is no service running that port 80. just robomotion run that port. but integromat didn't listen to it. it shows that error. since integromat is web-based webhook, can we only use port 80 or any port? if I test with postman apps as webhook and use port 9090 services running in robomotion. it works well. but not port 80. is it the problem from robomotion or port? @Mime

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with robomotion then your firewall rules. I think you should assure if robomotion is running on the correct port, and if that doesn't help, you should try to configure integromat to make requests against another port, e.g. `9090`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
sudo ufw enable
```

After that, you can check if it is working

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```